# Ruby: accumulate into a Set, or into an Array and sort afterwards?

Tags: arrays, ruby, time-complexity

I have a few hundred text files totaling a few million words.  I want the list of unique words, about a hundred thousand.  Everything fits in memory.

**Edit**: I want the actual list, not just how long the list is.

One way is to accumulate the words in a `Set`.

Another is to accumulate in an `Array`, and only at the end use `.sort.uniq`.

What considerations would favor one over another?

Comment: Using a Set will probably be faster, but the way to tell for sure is to write some test code, then use Benchmark, Fruity, or Benchmark.ips to tell you. I'd use the command-line and `sort -u | wc -l` though, as it'll run circles around Ruby for a task like that. In general your question is premature. You need to research, try, then when you run into a problem write a specific question about that particular problem. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)"

Comment: If you would also like to know how many times each word appears, you could use a hash with elements `word => <number of times word appears>`. The number of unique words is simply the number of keys in the hash. As sets are implemented with hashes, I would expect the use of a set or a hash would be similar in terms of efficiency.

Comment: Tin Man is right:  doing as much of the work as possible with shell commands is faster.  I'm still waiting for my sysadmin to install gnu parallel, but a rough benchmark suggests that this will be a dozen times faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby is the wrong tool.  Much faster is `tr " " "\n" < *.txt | sort -u`, possibly elaborated with GNU `parallel` if there's some `sed` to sprinkle in.  If further processing needs Ruby, do only that part in Ruby.